# Example of central limit theorem fail due to dependence (for tuition)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I want to get better understanding why the central limit theorem can fail. I have seen examples that the theorem fails when the variables are not identically distributed, and when the variance is not finite.

Can you suggest an example where CLT fails due to dependence? It is intended for tuition, so it is good if the example does not seem too contrived, and perhaps uses one of the common continuous probability distributions.

Comment: Probably the simplest example of this is the sequence $X_1, X_1, X_1, \ldots,$ when the distribution of $X_1$ is far from normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(X=1)=P(X=-1) = 1/2$ and let the summands $X_n$ all equal $X$. They are obviously identically distributed, but obviously not independent.  Their sum $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ (which is $nX$) does not have a gaussian limit.  For another example, let $X_n = (-1)^n X$.  Again, identically distributed but not independent. Their sum (in this case $S_n=0$ if $n$ is even, $S_n=-X$ if $n$ is odd) doesn't have a gaussian limit in a different way, with a different scaling.

But maybe these are too contrived?  Maybe, but I think any counterexample will be a bit like these.  The CLT is about cancellation of sums of random variables, and these examples show the extremes of *no cancellation* and *maximal cancellation*.  Any counterexample will partake of some of these behaviors.

Comment: I like this answer. Is it possible to say a bit more about what you mean by cancellation?

Comment: I'm sure there is a formal theory of this, but for me, it's just buzz words my smarter colleagues use.  Certainly for our beloved $\sqrt n$ scaling to hold you need  the sums of the covariances to vanish in the limit.  Have you ever seen a "Galton's quincunx" toy (aka "bean machine")?  The motions to the left or right at successive layers of the gizmo tend to cancel on the average, so the net motion is usually of order $\pm\sqrt n$ instead of $\pm n$.